# Logging Errors from Multiple Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, logging

I am using the built in Java logger to log errors (caught in a `try-catch` statement) to a text file.

One of my loggers is being accessed by multiple threads.  Each threads writes properly, but the issue is that when two threads try to write at the same time, one of them ends up creating a new file, so I end up with two files `log.txt` and `log.txt.1`.

How can I synchronize these actions so that I am not creating a new file?

For reference, here is how I setup the logger for the class in question:

```
// Set up the network logger
private void LoggerSetup() throws IOException{
    Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ClientConnect.class.getName());

    File path = new File("logs/");
    File file = new File(path, "NetworkLogs.txt");

    path.mkdirs();
    if(!file.exists())
        file.createNewFile();

    FileHandler fileHandler;
    SimpleFormatter formatter;

    try {
        fileHandler = new FileHandler(file.getPath(), true);
        LOGGER.addHandler(fileHandler);
        formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
        fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter);
    } catch (IOException | SecurityException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

And here is an example of this logger being used:

```
catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "ClientConnect", e);
    }
```

Comment: Try running the setup from a `static` block in your main class.

Comment: Great call.  I called it from a static context and it seems to have resolved the issue.